# Crystal: Sort by multiple groups

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports-2008

Good afternoon all;

Currently I have a crystal report that displays as such;

```
{ReceivingHospital}
{CallTtype}  {Date}  {SendingHospital}  {Time1}  {Time2}
```

I would like it to break down by receiving hospital then beneath that show all "Major" call types and sum them. Then Beneath that all "Moderate" call types with a sum, and then all "Minor" call types beneath that with a sum also. And, I want to keep all the associated details listed in that same order. I was thinking I could add multiple group headers and place the call type in that, but that does not seem to be working.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the relation between hospital and call types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to create a group for {ReceivingHospital} and then a second group for {CallType}. You can then create a group sum based on {CallType}. If it still does not work and you are working with multiple tables you should check whether you have joined your tables correctly.